# fullcalendar in VB.Net ASP MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, fullcalendar

I try to make a scheduler using fullcalendar. I cannot find a tutorial that use vb.net. So i follow this tutorial [A complete web diary system for jQuery and C# MVC](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/638674/Full-calendar-A-complete-web-diary-system-for-jQue) by converting c# code into vb.net. But i have problem to display the calendar. I have added fullcalendar.js to my scripts folder and fullcalendar.css into content folder. But the result shows nothing. A blank page. This is my html code:

```
<div class="row">
<div id='calendar' style="width:65%"></div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#calendar').fullcalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            defaultView: 'agendaDay',
            editable: true,
            allDaySlot: false,
            selectable: true,
            slotMinutes: 15,
        });
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Did you get this working?

Comment: Are you still just getting a blank page? Are there any errors in the console?

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the CSS and JS on the page. Just adding them to the folders is probably not enough.

- Include them in `_Layout.cshtml` (which makes them available on all pages)
- Include them in the current view (this page only)

Example:

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/fullcalendar.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/fullcalendar.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Also you have an unclosed `<div class="row">`